Detect multiple parent (and child) contours with openCV
I'm working on a Python script that processes images using OpenCV to detect contours and classify them into parent and child contours. The script generates:

A labeled visualization of the contours (blue borders for parents,
green borders for children).
A CSV file containing metrics about the
contour hierarchy.

Problem: The script fails to correctly detect and label multiple parent contours. It identifies only one parent contour (misclassified) and mislabels the others.
Expected Output:

The image should display:


4 parent contours (blue borders).
The first 3 parents should have 4 child contours each (green
borders).
The last parent (a triangle) should have no children.


Metrics output (example with dummy data):




Label
Parent Label
Width
Height
Area




parent_1
parent_1
2480
3508
8693853.0


contour_1
parent_1
710
452
161933.0


contour_2
parent_1
1251
1062
795647.0


contour_3
parent_1
709
1324
736735.0


contour_4
parent_1
869
943
812353.0


parent_2
parent_2
2480
3508
8693853.0


contour_1
parent_2
710
452
161933.0


contour_2
parent_2
1251
1062
795647.0


contour_3
parent_2
709
1324
736735.0


contour_4
parent_2
869
943
812353.0


parent_3
parent_3
2480
3508
8693853.0


contour_1
parent_3
710
452
161933.0


contour_2
parent_3
1251
1062
795647.0


contour_3
parent_3
709
1324
736735.0


contour_4
parent_3
869
943
812353.0


parent_4
parent_4
869
943
812353.0



Here is the script:
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

def process_image_with_multiple_parents(image_path, output_dir):
    # Load image
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    if image is None:
        print(f"Error: Unable to load image from {image_path}")
        return

    # Grayscale
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Thresholding
    _, thresholded_image = cv2.threshold(gray_image, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    # Find parent and child contours
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresholded_image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    if hierarchy is not None:
        hierarchy = hierarchy[0]  # Flatten the hierarchy array

    # Store metrics
    metrics = []
    image_height, image_width = thresholded_image.shape[:2]

    # Create a labeled visualization
    labeled_image = cv2.cvtColor(thresholded_image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    parent_count = 0
    for idx, (contour, h) in enumerate(zip(contours, hierarchy)):
        # Identify top-level contours (parents)
        if h[3] == -1:  # No parent
            parent_count += 1
            parent_label = f"parent_{parent_count}"

            # Draw parent contour
            cv2.drawContours(labeled_image, [contour], -1, (255, 0, 0), 2)  # Blue for parent
            cx, cy = tuple(np.mean(contour, axis=0).astype(int)[0])  # Centroid of parent
            cv2.putText(labeled_image, parent_label, (cx - 20, cy), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)

            # Save metrics for the parent contour
            x, y, width, height = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            parent_area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
            metrics.append({
                "label": parent_label,
                "parent_label": parent_label,  # Parent references itself
                "width": width,
                "height": height,
                "area": parent_area
            })

            # child contours
            child_count = 0
            for child_idx, (child_contour, child_h) in enumerate(zip(contours, hierarchy)):
                if child_h[3] == idx:  # Child of the current parent
                    child_count += 1
                    child_label = f"contour_{child_count}"

                    # Save metrics for the child contours
                    x, y, width, height = cv2.boundingRect(child_contour)
                    area = cv2.contourArea(child_contour)
                    metrics.append({
                        "label": child_label,
                        "parent_label": parent_label,
                        "width": width,
                        "height": height,
                        "area": area
                    })

                    # Draw the child contours
                    cv2.drawContours(labeled_image, [child_contour], -1, (0, 255, 0), 5)  # Green for child
                    cx, cy = tuple(np.mean(child_contour, axis=0).astype(int)[0])  # Centroid of child
                    cv2.putText(labeled_image, child_label, (cx - 20, cy), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)

    # Save the labeled visualization
    os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)
    labeled_image_path = os.path.join(output_dir, "labeled_image.png")
    cv2.imwrite(labeled_image_path, labeled_image)
    print(f"Labeled image saved to: {labeled_image_path}")

    # Save the parent/child metrics to a CSV file
    metrics_df = pd.DataFrame(metrics)
    csv_path = os.path.join(output_dir, "contour_metrics.csv")
    metrics_df.to_csv(csv_path, index=False)
    print(f"Metrics saved to: {csv_path}")


# Run it
if __name__ == "__main__":
    image_path = "test_image.png"  # image path
    output_dir = "output"
    process_image_with_multiple_parents(image_path, output_dir)





I see that your code correctly identifies the 4 parent contours. Why do you say it misclassifies?

@Cincinnatus Parent contours are in blue, child contours are in green. dalek_fred, contours are drawn around white areas of the image. Since your background is white, the parent contour goes around the border of the image. You could invert the image during thresholding, but that would probably not give you the child contours that you want.

invert the picture... foreground must be white, background must be black. that is probably gonna give you what you want.

@dalek_fredIs:  this is what look like? Here is link: https://ibb.co/qFvkmf6 and https://ibb.co/WcWHMsy

@ChristophRackwitz Your solution worked. But whyis contour analysis on an inverted image the solution? It seems a bit counterintuitive to me.

I solved all four parent. But I cannot get values for contours. Here is link: https://ibb.co/qFvkmf6. I got the last parent 4 for triangle.  As you saying that The script fails to correctly detect and label multiple parent contours. It identifies only one parent contour (misclassified) and mislabels the others.

not inverted. that's not the point.
